gitlab-ci: Including external jobs only for merge requests
I'm trying to configure a CI pipeline which includes jobs from other project, but only for merge requests. According to GitLab documentation, I can use rules with include and $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE is supported there, however the following doesn't run the included jobs at all:
include:
  - project: "configs/gitlab-ci"
    file: "checks.gitlab-ci.yml"
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
        when: always


Using the same rules I can pick locally defined jobs to be run in merge request, but it doesn't work for include. I haven't really found anything useful on the topic, apart from the documentation linked above.
How can I make include work only for merge requests?

I've found a GitLab issue describing this problem: gitlab-org/gitlab#393232 so it seems this is at least for now broken.

Oh that is unfortunate.... Let's hope that this is one of the issues that get addressed quickly. Maybe you can comment on the issue to bump it to the top

I currently have a similar setup where I want to include something only for scheduled pipelines. This works for me:
include:
  - project: project_name
    file:
      - gitlab-ci.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"' # Only include on scheduled pipelines for now

So I would assume the follwoing should work for you:
include:
  - project: "configs/gitlab-ci"
    file: "checks.gitlab-ci.yml"
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"


Looking at the documentation I would assume the same, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm using GitLab 16.11.6-ee if it makes a difference.
